# Error in Sending a mp3 files using Python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am trying to send mp3 files through python. Here is the following code -

```
for v in videos:

    Thread(target=video_download, args=(handler,v,videos)).start()


def video_download(handler,v,videos):


    try:
        ydl_opts['format'] = 'mp4'
        ydl(ydl_opts).download([v])
    except:
        ydl_opts['format'] = 'best'
        ydl(ydl_opts).download([v])     
    mp3  = open('./'+v+'.mp3', "r+").read()
    handler.send_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=%s.mp3' % videos[v])
    handler.wfile.write(mp3)
    handler.end_headers()
```

It downloads m4a format video from youtube and converts it to mp3 files. The download and conversion part is working perfectly, it uses threading, but while sending the file using wfile.write() i receive the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/Users/Keshav/Documents/Github/Webserver/webserver/Downld.py", line 37, in video_download
    handler.send_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=%s.mp3' % videos[v])
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 401, in send_header
    self.wfile.write("%s: %s\r\n" % (keyword, value))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 324, in write
    self.flush()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sendall'
```

The same thing works perfectly fine if i implement multiprocessing instead of threading. But its processing it serially instead of parallel.

Comment: Can you show us more of your main code? Like how is handler defined, etc.

Comment: The following links has the full code [Base Server](https://github.com/medakeshav/Webserver/blob/master/Base.py) and [Downloader](https://github.com/medakeshav/Webserver/blob/master/Downld.py).
Im running a threaded basehttp server and using a router functionality, the handler borrows methods of the base http server which has variable and methods for sending receiving header messages and sending and receiving files